# Reading not quite correct .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have .csv file in the following format:

```
A, B, C
...
2.0, 4.0, 2.0^ 
...
7.3, 1.3, 6.8^ 
...
```

Where ^ means any combination of symbols starting with "`,`" for example `,,,,d..k3.4,,,,2,3f,,,` in the end there is always end of line. I expect my output frame will be:

```
     A   B   C
    ...
    2.0 4.0 2.0 
    ...
    7.3 1.3 6.8
    ...
```

How can I read this file into frame?

Comment: Try this for example `read.table(filename, sep =',',fill=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example is not clear. You should maybe show us 2 or 3 lines of your text file.

Assuming your file is like this :

```
TEXT <- 'A, B, C
2.0, 4.0, 2.0,,,,,d..k3.4,,,,2,3f,,,
7.3, 1.3, 6.8,,,,,,2,3f,,,'
```

You can read it using `read.table` with option `fill=TRUE`

```
dat <- read.table(text=TEXT,header=FALSE,sep=',',fill=TRUE) 
dat <- dat[,colSums(is.na(dat))<nrow(dat)]
(dat <- dat[-1,])
  V1   V2   V3      V8 V9 V10 V12 V13
2 2.0  4.0  2.0 d..k3.4 NA       2  3f
3 7.3  1.3  6.8          2  3f  NA
```

Comment: Yes, but also I need the first row to be header

Comment: @midas the first don't have enough columns to be the hedar. I mean there are only 3 letters..

Comment: @midas The column names can be added manually after the fact.

Comment: Yes, but conceptually they are header. In each row I have 3 separated numeric values. But after third values instead of symbol of new line I have some garbage and symbol of new line. Is it possible to read this file into frame?

Comment: @midas why not to add the expected "frame"( I guess you mean data.frame) to your question?